# Are photons in laser entangled?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, laser

When energy is pumped into the atom, photon is being emitted which would then get absorbed by another already excited atom causing the atom to emits 2 similar photon. Soon more photons are produced in this manner which escapes through a hole as seen as laser light, my question is are all these photons entangled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ideal laser, there is no entanglement whatsoever between successive emerging photons.  This occurs because a laser state is supposed to be a [coherent state (Glauber state)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states) of the electromagnetic field.  One of the properties of such a state is that removing one quantum of energy from it does not actually change the state of the system.  (The coherent states are eigenstates of the annihilation operator.)  So, essentially, when a photon is released from the laser cavity, the state of the cavity does not change.  (This is consistent with energy conservation because there is a continuous pumping of energy into the cavity.)

As a consequence of this lack of entanglement, the laser photons are emitted in a Poisson process.  That means the emission time of any one photon is uncorrelated with the emission times of all the others.  There are no higher order correlations either.  (This can be described by saying that the laser is perfectly coherent at all orders.)

Real lasers deviate somewhat from this ideal somewhat, for various reasons, some obvious, some not.  (A laser that is only turned on for a finite time cannot be perfectly coherent.  There are also more complicated imperfections that can arise from the way the system is pumped if more than two states are involved.)  However, in general, the goal of a laser system is to produce a beam that is as close to a perfectly coherent structure as possible.

Comment: Does the 2nd photon which was stimulated have any correlation in time to the original photon? Simultaneous?

Comment: @PhysicsDave Photons in a laser do not come in pairs.  As I said, "the emission time of any one photon is uncorrelated with the emission times of all the others."

Comment: So it's interesting that the stimulated emission comes in a Poisson distribution but that in the laser many of the photons have similar phase ...I'm not an expert just trying to understand it.

Comment: @PhysicsDave “Laser radiation is produced in a resonant cavity where the resonant frequency of the cavity is the same as the frequency associated with the atomic electron transitions providing energy flow into the field. As energy in the resonant mode builds up, the probability for stimulated emission, in that mode only, increases. That is a positive feedback loop in which the amplitude in the resonant mode increases exponentially until some non-linear effects limit it. ”

Comment: I think you should hold your horses a bit, lasing is a quantum mechanical phenomenon and if a single wave function can be obtained for the system there may be entanglement see  http://agencia.fapesp.br/experiment-obtains-entanglement-of-six-light-waves-with-a-single-laser/28637/  . Also https://physicsworld.com/a/laser-beams-are-entangled-in-space/ .  Also I would not confuse coherence, which means fixed phases  in the wavefunctions, with non entanglement.

Comment: @annav That article is about entanglement of two different laser beams with one-another, which is an entirely separate question.  And the coherence you describe is only first order coherence, whereas ideal lasers are perfectly coherent at all orders, which includes quantum effects.

Comment: If there exists one quantum mechanical function, then there is entanglement by definition. just maybe not clear conservation laws to be utlized.. The second link is  with one laser beam

Comment: @annav agree, I thought coherent photons were, by definition, entangled, hence the goal of optical quantum computing to A) avoid decoherence and B) why photon measurement on one side of a double slit "collapses" the diffraction pattern. The diffraction pattern does not collapse then you measure an independently pumped laser.  Only photons from the original laser can impact the diffraction... seems like entanglement, no? otherwise, measurement of one slit would just create a single slit result on the other side, not the particularized result

Comment: @donlan of course it is entanglement, but the total coherent quantum mechanical wave function includes the source

Comment: @annav that isn’t clear.  Take an electron and shoot it at the double slit one at a time.  The electron is discrete and observed prior to firing, and yet escapes the double slit with a diffraction pattern consistent with coherent flow.  The source has nothing to do with the result at all.

Comment: The electron does not show by itself a pattern. sigle electron is a dot . looks random but the probability distribution shows the pattern , not the single electron. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles